# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named numpy, but I already have it installed

Tags: python, module, lib

I have this problem, with numpy and Pyserial, I alredy have installed this lib.
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHisF.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVlyr.png)

I try uninstall and install again but nothing

Comment: This usually means you have more than one python installed. How do you run the failing program? I don't know whether you run via "python" or "python3", but for example you could assess its pip via `python3 -m pip list`. You could also `pip3 --version` and see if its in your python distribution.

Comment: Before the the import numpy line run import sys, and then print( sys.executable ). I would expect this to point to your default python installation which probably has no numpy.